# Globalizing Variable from Function

Tags: javascript, html, scope, html5-canvas

I've been tasked with providing a live video feed on a legacy machine that runs IE6. To do this, I'm using a Flash based shim for recreating the Canvas object(no support in IE<10). Here is the ReadMe: https://www.mapmsg.com/static/3rdparty/fxcanvas-0/ReadMe.html

Now then, I currently get imageData like this:

```
this.imageData=this.context.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height)
```

The shim documentation doesn't simply use `getImageData`. The reason being:

> We cannot use canvas image data as it declared in specs, because of IE using extremely ineffective memory manager so it may eats all available memory in some circumstances. So that fxCanvas is using slightly different image data format.

Example:

```
 var cv = document.getElementById("cv");
var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
ctx.setFillStyle("#ff0")
    .setStrokeStyle("#0ff")
    .strokeRect(10, 20, 30, 30)
    .fillRect(30, 40, 50, 50)
    .invoke("getImageData", 0, 0, cv.width, cv.height, function (imageData) {
        // ... processing image data
    });
```

The idea being, all the image processing is done in the built-in function inside of `.invoke`.

ALL of that being said, my problem is fairly simple. I can't do all the image processing in that function. I want to return `imageData` into `this.imageData` so I can use it in other functions before finally putting it back into the canvas with `putImageData`.

So, my dumb attempt at this was:

```
this.context.invoke("getImageData",0,0,this.width,this.height, function(imgdat){return imgdat});

this.imageData= imgdat;
```

Doesn't work. `imgdat` is not declared. No matter what I try, I can't seem to populate `this.imageData` with the image data from `.invoke`

This is my first experience with javascript ever, and I'm attempting to edit code I did not write (https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg/blob/master/jsmpeg.min.js). I would greatly prefer to get that data into the format the program already uses instead of re-writing everything to make it all happen in the `.invoke` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a simple scope resolution problem.

You receive `imgdat` inside the function which is a callback, but once the function finishes the variable is gone.
I don't see your `this.imageData` on your first snippet.

I assume that what you need to do is:

```
var cv = document.getElementById("cv");
var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");
var self = this; // <------------ important detail
ctx.setFillStyle("#ff0")
    .setStrokeStyle("#0ff")
    .strokeRect(10, 20, 30, 30)
    .fillRect(30, 40, 50, 50)
    .invoke("getImageData", 0, 0, cv.width, cv.height, function (imageData) {
        // ... processing image data
        self.imageData = imageData; //instead of this.imageData
    });

//Now you can use imageData here.
this.imageData (...);
```

The `this` keywork in javascript works differently from what you are used on other languages.

Comment: If the problem is only because of variable scope, these can help you understand better the `this` keyword on javascript: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49872/using-var-self-this-or-bindthis, https://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: You are correct, thank you. I did try this solution, and I thought it did not work, but that was only because I was misreading a different problem. Thank you.